# what's the best way to check for required information in a textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have multiple textboxes on my form which are bound to data on a database, some information is required and others are not, I want an errorprovider to be set to the controls that are required and I have this for all current textboxes by using a typeof, I was just wondering how would be the best way to implement an errorprovider for all required textboxes?

thanks in advance =]

Comment: check http://www.dotnetperls.com/errorprovider

Comment: Are you looking for a generic way to "tack one on" automatically based on some criteria?  Since you say you already "have this for all current textboxes", I'm not sure what you are really asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PageValidating event.
When the form opens and the user adds all the info he wanted and presses Next the event is triggered. There you can make some validation.
For example:
1.If you want to see if the ckeckbox is not empty you can make something like that:

```
if(textBox1.Text != null)
   e.Valid = true;
else
    MessageBox.Show("Add some text in checkbox please","Error",
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
```

2.If you want to validate the input somehow you can use Regex, like that:

```
string pattern = @"[a-zA-Z0-9@]{6,12}";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
if (regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text))
    e.Valid = true;
else
    MessageBox.Show("Add some text in checkbox please","Error",
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
```